# CC per HP in a 2-stroke engine?

Tags: engine, small-engine, two-stroke, horsepower

I have a bunch of 2-stroke engines and the websites that I found only tell me about 4-cycle engines. Do you happen to know the ratio of cc to HP?

Comment: Depends on who makes it, quality etc etc

Comment: It doesn't need to be exact, just close.

Comment: A google search should give you all you need to know, names such as Husquvarna, Stihl, Brioggs & Stratton come to mind.

Comment: A very broad rule-of-thumb would be that a 2-stroke produces twice the power of the same capacity 4-stroke engine, because it fires twice as often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search gives:
[image]

So, you can work out the power per cc for each and take an average.
You might, of course, need to check out larger engines and see how the performance is affected.

Comment: This appears to be roughly in line with GDR light motorcycles made by Simson:
http://www.mopedfreunde-oldenburg.de/html/simson_s51.html
http://www.mopedfreunde-oldenburg.de/html/simson_s70.html